# Does docker take care of Angular dependencies on its own?

Tags: angular, docker

I have an angular application and I'm trying to dockerize it as follows:

```
FROM node:latest as node
COPY APP /APP
WORKDIR /APP
RUN npm install
RUN ng build --base-href /static/
```

However, I have also used many libraries such as Angular animations, HttpClient, etc. I wanted to know when I build using the dockerfile, will the dependencies be taken care of automatically using the package.json file?

Comment: Nope, you will have to run `RUN npm install` in the `Dockerfile`

Comment: You mean something like what I have mentioned above? Or something else?

Comment: As long as you copy the package.json to the image and run npm install the dependencies will be taken care of

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot!